# Reading NSData in parts

Tags: ios, out-of-memory

I am implementing extensions in ios8. In this `import` function returns a url. I need to read data from it and save in my app.

Here is the code.

```
NSFileCoordinator *fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] init];
    NSError *error;
    __block NSData *data;
    [fileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:url options:0 error:&error byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL) {
        data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:newURL];
//saving in document directory
    }];
```

My question is, if file is too big, `dataWithContentsOfURL` results in crash due to out of memory.

I wanted a method to read data from that url in parts, save in my documents, then read next part and keep appending. Thus it won't have memory issue.

Can someone help.

Comment: So you want someone to write the code for you?

Comment: Not code. Give a hint. Any framwork, library name.

Answer (score 0):

Found two solutions.
1- Used NSURLConnection. Using `NSFileHandle` wrote data in file.

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data1{
//    [data appendData:data1];
    [self.currentFileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
    [self.currentFileHandle writeData:data1];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    [self.currentFileHandle closeFile];
    self.currentFileHandle = nil;
}
```

2. Instead of converting it in data and then saving. Used following to copy file.

   ```
   NSFileCoordinator* fileCoordinator = [[NSFileCoordinator alloc] initWithFilePresenter:nil];
   ```

   [fileCoordinator coordinateReadingItemAtURL:url options:NSFileCoordinatorReadingWithoutChanges error:nil byAccessor:^(NSURL *newURL) {

NSFileManager * fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];

```
NSError * error;

NSArray *paths = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];


NSURL *urlDestination = [paths lastObject];
                    urlDestination = [urlDestination URLByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]];


if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[urlDestination relativePath]]){


[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[urlDestination relativePath] error:nil];

}
```

BOOL success = [fileManager copyItemAtURL:url toURL:urlDestination error:&error];
if (success) {
}
}];

> I used 2nd solution. Sorry for wrong alignment. I tried a lot, but not
>   coming properly.